# How to word-wrap text to a given row length in characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to word-wrap text into an array of rows (phrases / lines) with max length of N characters. If a word is bigger than the max row length the word should be cut to the length.

**Edit: max length of n characters is never less than 100 chars, I used 10 to show you my code is not working properly**

```js
const sentence =`Wake has three meanings as a noun, and, yes, just about as many meanings as a verb! So get set. To wake is come out of sleep, a verb you'll recognize from "Wake up! You're asleep at the wheel!" You can wake feelings, as well as the people who are having them. The wake before the funeral caused Mike to wake from his depression and decide to live life to the fullest. His first act was to water ski; he eventually mastered staying upright while crossing the wake of the boat that was towing him.`

// shorten with max characters of 10
console.log(shorten(sentence, 10));

function shorten(str, maxLen) {

  if(str.length <= maxLen) return [str];
  let max, min = 0, i = 1;
  const result = [];
    while (maxLen * i < str.length) {
    max = str.lastIndexOf(' ', maxLen * i);
    result.push(str.substr(min, max));
    min = max + 1;
    i++;
    }
  return result;
 
}
```

The issue is my code dos't work correctly as you see.

**The desired out put would be:**

```
["Wake has", "three", "meanings", "as a noun,", ...]  // each one has length of : 8 - 5 - 8 - 10
```

Comment: What if you have an 11-letter word?

Comment: Then : ["10-letter word"]

Comment: Please use complete sentences to be more explicit. If your "max characters" is 10, then the 11-letter word exceeds your limit. How do you want to handle that?

Comment: max length of n characters is never less than 100 chars

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give 2 examples of expected output with a smaller usecase

Comment: Assuming you dont have >100 letter words: [`.{1,100}(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/QDUEPt/1)

Comment: @markalex How can we use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the task is to word-wrap text in a monospaced font.
Somehow that works:

```js
const sentence = `Some-long-string-should-be-cut-to-10 Wake has three         meanings as a noun, and, yes, just about as many meanings as a verb! So get set. To wake is come out of sleep, a verb you'll recognize from "Wake up! You're asleep at the wheel!" You can wake feelings, as well as the people who are having them. The wake before the funeral caused Mike to wake from his depression and decide to live life to the fullest. His first act was to water ski; he eventually mastered staying upright while crossing the wake of the boat that was towing him.`

// shorten with max characters of 10
console.log(shorten(sentence, 10).map(str => str + ': ' + str.length));

function shorten(str, maxLen) {

    const phrases = [];
    let phrase = '';
    let word = '';

    const addWord = () => {
        if(word){
            phrase.length + word.length >= maxLen && addPhrase();
            phrase += (phrase ? ' ' : '') + word;
            word = '';
        }
    };

    const addPhrase = () => {
        if(phrase){
            phrases.push(phrase.length > maxLen ? phrase.substring(0, maxLen) : phrase);
            phrase = '';
        }
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        const c = str[i];
        c === ' ' ? addWord() : word += c;
    }

    addWord();
    addPhrase();

    return phrases;
}
```

Comment: @RaolmAX you are welcome. improved a bit... check the latest version. also i'd urge you to upvote (the arrow up) and accept (the checkbox) my answer so i will get reputation points and have motivation to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: This might not be very good performance wise though. I might be wrong, but looping through all characters feels as if its not efficient.

Comment: @Martijn when I write my own parsers char-by-char i always get not bad performance. The problem when you want to extend the parser like handling quotes, commas, dots and so on you always would want to go down on the character level

Comment: @RaolmAX added trimming of long words + fixed a bug of adding an empty phrase

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex [`(?=\S).{0,99}\S(?!\S)|\S{100}`](https://regex101.com/r/QDUEPt/3) in conjunction with [.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to find desired blocks of symbols (for parameter equal 100).

Here regex matches:

- `(?=\S).{0,99}\S(?!\S)` block of one to hundred symbols, that begin and end with non-whitespace symbols, and followed by either whitespace or end of line:

  - `(?=\S)` lookaround that checks first symbol to be non-whitespace,
  - `.{0,99}` between 0 and 99 of any symbols, except newlines,
  - `\S` matches last symbol to be non-whitespace,
  - `(?!\S)` checks that match is followed by whitespace symbol (to prevent wrapping in the middle of the word)
- `\S{100}` a hundred of consequent non-whitespace symbols: for cases of very long words, that span over maximum expected line length.

Example of code:

```js
const sentence =`Wake has three meanings as a noun, and, yes, just about as many meanings as a verb! So get set. To wake is come out of sleep, a verb you'll recognize from "Wake up! You're asleep at the wheel!" You can wake feelings, as well as the people who are having them. The wake before the funeral caused Mike to wake from his depression and decide to live life to the fullest. His first act was to water ski; he eventually mastered staying upright while crossing the wake of the boat that was towing him.`

console.log(wrapLines(sentence, 100));

function wrapLines(str, maxLen){
    let reg = new RegExp('(?=\\S).{0,'+(maxLen-1)+'}\\S(?!\\S)|\\S{'+maxLen+'}', 'gm')
    console.log(reg)
    return Array.from(str.matchAll(reg), (m) => m[0]);
}
```

Comment: should trim spaces at the start with `\S` - `\S.{1,9}(?!\S)`. also doesn't trim overflowing words properly. on big text is a bit slower than iterating characters manually.

Comment: also doesn't handle multiple spaces

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev, thanks for input. Updated according to new information in question and your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to,

```
const sentence = `Wake has three meanings as a noun, and, yes, just about as many meanings as a verb! So get set. To wake is come out of sleep, a verb you'll recognize from "Wake up! You're asleep at the wheel!" You can wake feelings, as well as the people who are having them. The wake before the funeral caused Mike to wake from his depression and decide to live life to the fullest. His first act was to water ski; he eventually mastered staying upright while crossing the wake of the boat that was towing him.`;

console.log(shorten(sentence, 10));

function shorten(str, maxLen) {
  if (str.length <= maxLen) return [str];
  
  const result = [];
  let startIndex = 0;
  let endIndex = maxLen;
  
  while (endIndex < str.length) {
    while (str[endIndex] !== ' ' && endIndex > startIndex) {
      endIndex--;
    }
    
    result.push(str.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
    startIndex = endIndex + 1;
    endIndex = startIndex + maxLen;
  }
  
  result.push(str.substring(startIndex));
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It gives me more than 10 chars .

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, if you dont have huge amounts of text this might be doable:

```js
function textSplitter(text, maxLength){
    var currentPos = 0;
    var result = [];
    while(currentPos < text.length){
        const probe = text.substring(currentPos, currentPos+maxLength); // take max length
        const lastSpace = probe.lastIndexOf(" "); // track back to last space
   
        const item = probe.substring(0, lastSpace); // take what you want
        result.push(item); // store it
        currentPos += item.length + 1; // 1 is the space
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is untested code, and I expect that you need a +1 or -1 at some spots, but this is an example.
(If someone wants to tweak it and fix it, feel free to do so).

Comment: It doesn't handle the case where the phrase is ending with a word's end. Also it overflows the text's length. Doesn't handle word trimming and multiple spaces. Otherwise promising, faster than my solution with iterating characters, but my solution isn't optimized at all, too much reading `length` properties

Comment: yeah, ran out of time to test it, but I hoped it showed the intent